# PHPExcel and Function AVERAGEIF

Tags: php, phpexcel

I try to realize the "`AVERAGEIF`" Function in PHPExcel, but Im not able to make this work **(Excel always claims: unreadable/corrupt files)**.
The result "should" be:

```
setCell('AG1','=AVERAGEIF(B1:AF1;">0")')
```

PHPExcel does not complain, but Excel cannot open it. I already tried many versions with quotation marks, escaping the formula quotation marks, with comma or semicolon - nothing seems to work.
Anyone had this issue before and knows a trick, how to solve it?

Thanks!
Christoph

Comment: Try opening the file in notepad, andcheck what error is being thrown...

Comment: What Writer are you using to save this spreadsheet file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you've set a calculation engine locale, PHPExcel requires a `,` separator for Excel formula function arguments, not a `;` so

```
setCell('AG1','=AVERAGEIF(B1:AF1;">0")')
```

should be

```
setCell('AG1','=AVERAGEIF(B1:AF1,">0")')
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that already - if I am using a comma, then Excel wont say "its comrrupted", but the formula turns to: AVERAGEIF(B1:AF1,"&gt;0") - something obviously escaped that String...

Comment: Which Writer are you using? I've tested this already this morning, and it work for Excel2007 while the Excel5 writer discards it, because it isn't a core function in xls files; but PHPExcel will not escape any string to html entities unless it's using the HTML Writer

Comment: You are absolutely right - it was an own function, that escaped that String at the very end, absolutely my fault - sorry for that! and thanks!